# Gaussian Blur Shader less intense on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, love2d

I am writing an android game using Love2D in which I am using a Gaussian Blur Shader to get a bloom effect, however I am testing it on PC, and the results on PC and Android are **very** different, to the point of making the shader useless on Android.

Here is how the PC version looks like: 
[image: Running on my PC]

And Here is how the Android version looks like: 
[image: Running on android]

Both are running with the following shaders, doing a pass with offset direction vertical and horizontal.

```
// Vertex Shader:
#ifdef GL_ES
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
precision highp float;
#else
precision mediump float;
#endif
#endif

varying vec2 coordinate2b;
varying vec2 coordinate1b;
varying vec2 coordinate0f;
varying vec2 coordinate1f;
varying vec2 coordinate2f;

uniform vec2 offset_direction;

vec4 position(mat4 transform_projection, vec4 vertex_position)
{
  coordinate2b = VertexTexCoord.xy + -3.230769 * offset_direction;
  coordinate1b = VertexTexCoord.xy + -1.384615 * offset_direction;
  coordinate0f = VertexTexCoord.xy + 0.000000 * offset_direction;
  coordinate1f = VertexTexCoord.xy + 1.384615 * offset_direction;
  coordinate2f = VertexTexCoord.xy + 3.230769 * offset_direction;
  return transform_projection * vertex_position;
}

// Fragment Shader:
#ifdef GL_ES
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
precision highp float;
#else
precision mediump float;
#endif
#endif

varying vec2 coordinate2b;
varying vec2 coordinate1b;
varying vec2 coordinate0f;
varying vec2 coordinate1f;
varying vec2 coordinate2f;

vec4 effect(vec4 color, Image texture, vec2 texture_coords, vec2 screen_coords)
{
  vec4 c = vec4(0.0);
  c += vec4(0.070270) * Texel(texture, coordinate2b);
  c += vec4(0.316216) * Texel(texture, coordinate1b);
  c += vec4(0.227027) * Texel(texture, coordinate0f);
  c += vec4(0.316216) * Texel(texture, coordinate1f);
  c += vec4(0.070270) * Texel(texture, coordinate2f);
  return c * color;
}
```

I am currently guessing the problem is with float precision, but I am not sure what I would have to do to fix that.

Comment: What's the value of offset_direction on each platform? I presume it's related to the screen resolution, so do the screen resolutions match?

Comment: It's actually the same in both since I am rendering the scene to an intermediate canvas and then scaling this canvas to fit the screensize

Comment: Is it possible the texture filtering settings are different? (i.e. linear filtering is enabled on PC, but disabled on Android)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Columbo, I found out two different problems when running the game on my android. 
First was that texture filtering was not linear, this making the scaling optimization not working and having weird problems with scaling.
Second, love2d for android is not supporting gamma correction, so when running on my phone the game was not rendering color correctly and the blur was not visible due to the dark background.

Always check for gamma correction!